# Does Array.Add method violates LSP?

Tags: c#, .net, oop, solid-principles, liskov-substitution-principle

`Array` class implements `IList` interface that has `Add` member. `Array.Add` invocation throws `NotSupportedException`. Is it a violation of **The Liskov Substitution Principle** or **The Interface Segregation Principle** or both of them?

Comment: Including a method on an interface that an implementer might not want to implement is good sign that you're violating the ISP, yes. Can't see what this has to do with LSP, though.

Comment: To me it seems also a volation of LSP since, if the code expects an `ICollection`, and is given an `Array`, it seems to fail on `Add` (stated by OP)

Comment: It should be `IList.Add` instead of `ICollection.Add`, while `NotSupportedException` is expected exception of `IList.Add` per https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ilist.add(v=vs.110).aspx. I don't think violate LSP.

Comment: @qxg, thanks, i changed the description

Comment: There are many classes in the BCL that either violated both LSP and ISP. This is the hard part of designing a reusable class library that has to be used for so many different use cases, while trying to keep the API intuitive to work with. There are more factors at play here than simply the SOLID principles. The [Framework Design Guidelines](https://www.amazon.com/Framework-Design-Guidelines-Conventions-Libraries/dp/0321545613) give some great clues about this.

Comment: It does violate LSP because you cannot freely pass an array to a method accepting an IList and call IList.Add(). From the definition on Wikipedia: `Liskov's notion of a behavioral subtype defines a notion of substitutability for objects; that is, if S is a subtype of T, then objects of type T in a program may be replaced with objects of type S without altering any of the desirable properties of that program (e.g. correctness).` Clearly if you pass an array and the method tries to call `.Add()` it will violate the correctness of the program. Documenting the exception doesn't make it OK.

Comment: Arrays are weakly-typed in .NET, many people consider it supporting co-variance to be a design mistake.  Luckily Java gets the blame for that one.  With a pock-mark like that, arrays implementing IList and not having an interface type suitable for arrays is but a minor next step.  Usability does sometimes trump purity.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is definitely a violation of the interface segregation principle. ISP states that components should only depend on interfaces that they actually require. `Array` implements `IList`, but clearly does not need or want all of the methods defined by `IList`, because it chooses to throw an exception to explain that it doesn't support `Add`. Furthermore, anything that needs an `Array` now has an `IList` despite not needing all of its methods (because anything that wants an array is clearly not worried about `Add`, since it doesn't work anyway). Not supporting an operation that your interface suggests that you implement is clearly an ISP violation; forcing consuming code to depend on an interface despite not needing all of it is also an ISP violation.

This *can* lead to a violation of the Liskov substitution principle. If code depends on an `IList`, LSP states that it should function correctly when passed *any* implementation of `IList`. However, when passed an `Array`, that code will now throw an exception any time it tries to call `Add`.

Whether this constitutes an LSP violation depends how you see exceptions with respect to LSP. If you approach it from the viewpoint that the exceptions are a part of the expected contract, then it's fine. The method conforms to its contract, and any code that calls `Add` without accounting for the possibility of an exception is at fault for not doing so.

If you're more of the opinion that `NotSupportedException` is considered an error or failing, then it's a clear LSP violation. Personally, I find that the SOLID principles support each other and are harder to address in a vacuum, so using the interface segregation principle as backup, I'd say that the interface says "I can do these things", so saying "actually, I can't do that thing" is an error, and therefore probably shouldn't be considered part of a valid contract. If the exception isn't part of the contract, then by throwing one, `Array` is violating `Add`'s contract, and is therefore breaking LSP.

Comment: AFAIK `IList<T>` is implemented explicitly in arrays, so you don't get the methods by default unless you cast to the interface. Otherwise an array acts similarly to an immutable list. This is perhaps a tradeoff for not having an `IReadonlyList` interface that simply enables indexed read access (although arrays also allow indexed write access), while still keeping the language somewhat pleasant to use.

Comment: The documentation of IList.Add states that "NotSupportedException" is an expected exception and it also lists the conditions for it to be thrown. That's why in my humble opinion it is *not* a liskov-violation. _"LSP states that it should function correctly when passed any implementation of IList"_ - here, throwing a NotSupportedException *is* included in "function correctly".

Comment: @Fildor: I disagree. Stating that something is not supported, although justified, will lead to different behavior from the program's perspective. It will lead to a missing functionality `Add`, which is, if I understood correctly, is what LSP is about.

Comment: @Stefan Then we may have a different understanding of "Liskov". For all I've learned this depends on Add's Contract. If it must be expected to be unsupported, then an impl. that does not supported is Liskov-OK, IMHO. If Add's contract would *not* include that, then of course it would be a violation. *I could be wrong, though.*

Comment: It is NOT OK. The Liskov Substitution Principle is presented in terms of mathematical logic which does not allow for exceptions due to some ill-defined "documentation".

Comment: I've added a little extra to my answer to clarify my views on the points being raised in these comments.

Comment: @MatthewWatson For all I know, it's about *semantics*. If not being supported is part of the *semantics*, then implemenations of a Subtype that do not support it are semantically correct. Implementations doing something different than adding *or not support adding* would be a violation. So disallowing the exception would be a violation of Liskov in this case (because it would strengthen a precondition, imho).

Comment: _"Exceptions
Exception  Condition
NotSupportedException 

The IList is read-only.

-or-

The IList has a fixed size. "_ Your point on the *documentation* is valid, though. I just considered the documentation to reflect the actual contract. We should be talking about the latter, indeed.

Comment: @Fildor Oh yes, didn't spot that bit! But because of that it means that it is never guaranteed to be safe to call `.Add()` which effectively means that any method that calls `.Add()` via `IList` is an accident waiting to happen. Passing an array to a method that accepts an `IList()` that doesn't explicitly document that it doesn't call `.Add()` would therefore be incorrect - this is why such a violation is such a bad thing.

Comment: @MatthewWatson I agree. It's totally inconvenient and I always wondered why in fact arrays implement IList ... but that's a different story, I guess.

Comment: It's even worse than that because you might think you could at least use `list.IsReadOnly` to detect if the list cannot have `.Add()` called - but unfortunately this `list.IsReadOnly` is false for array types. If you call the following method and pass an array to it, it returns false: `public static bool IsreadOnly(IList list) { return list.IsReadOnly; }`

Comment: @MatthewWatson Absolutely. I guess we could write a whole book about such "booby traps".

Answer (score 0):

**The Liskov Substitution Principle** -

> A program that uses an interface must not be confused by an
> implementation of that interface.

Arrays make an exception in case of implementation IList<>  - that is confused.

```
void Main() 
{ 
    var arr = new int[]{1,2,3}; 

    Test(arr);  
    
    void Test(IList<int> list)
    {
        list.Add(4);
    }
}
```